# TFS error: "the project file or web could not be found"

Tags: visual-studio

I've been dealing with this issue for weeks now but until today was unable to solve it. I have a solution with 5 projects in it. It downloads them just fine except for one. I could not figure out why... I get the error:

"the project file or web could not be found."

Comment: I had this issue while trying to open a solution file from a ZIP folder I had downloaded from Pluralsight. It worked after I hit "Extract All" in File Explorer and opened the solution from there.

Answer (score 1):

I dug into the solution file from file explorer and noticed that it was referencing the project from another folder outside the project (which I hadn't noticed existed till today). Once I downloaded that project from TFS it fixed the problem.

I figured since no where on google did I find this exact error message I'd post my fix here in case someone else runs into it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I pull changes from github and found out the one of the project is not loading and giving the "the project file or web could not be found" error. Actually I have changed project folder name for one of my project from "ImageProcessor" to "ImageProcessorCore" which was not updated in the VS Solution file. This post helped me to change This:

"ImageProcessor\ImageProcessorCore.csproj"

To

"ImageProcessorCore\ImageProcessorCore.csproj"

in my VS Solution file.

Answer (score 0):

this error also occurs when the .csproj file of any project in the solution is missing or deleted. so make sure the .csproj file exists. if not get a clone from a solution source or create one according to your project.